# HTML in gt is displaying correctly in windows but not linux

Tags: r, gt

I am creating a gt with custom html.  The gt renders correctly on my local windows machine, but when restoring using renv on a Red Hat Linux 7 server the html no longer renders correctly.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)


df <- tibble::tribble(
               ~region,          ~site, ~overall, ~baseline, ~direction,
         "Upper North",      "Site A",     49.1,      49.2,     "Down",
         "Upper North",      "Site B",     47.8,      48.1,     "Down",
         "Upper North",      "Site C",        1,      48.2,     "Down",
         "Upper North",      "Site D",        0,      50.7,     "Down",
       "Central North",      "Site E",     79.3,        84,     "Down",
       "Central North",      "Site F",     48.4,      89.2,     "Down",
       "Central North",      "Site G",     52.3,      64.5,     "Down",
       "Central North",      "Site H",     57.1,      45.1,       "Up",
       "Central North",      "Site I",        0,      59.4,     "Down",
          "Lower North",     "Site J",     41.5,      53.9,     "Down",
          "Lower North",     "Site K",     55.2,      64.5,     "Down",
         "Upper South",      "Site L",     37.1,        40,     "Down",
       "Central South",      "Site M",     22.2,      52.3,     "Down",
       "Central South",      "Site N",      4.3,        34,     "Down",
         "Lower South",      "Site O",        0,      82.1,     "Down",
         "Lower South",      "Site P",     35.3,      43.1,     "Down",
  "Specialty Products",      "Site Q",     47.8,      55.8,     "Down",
  "Specialty Products",      "Site R",     60.8,        56,       "Up"
  )



assign_arrow <- function(direction) {
  if(direction == "Up") {
    return("<div> <span style='color:red'> <big><big><big><big><big> &#11014;</big></big></big></big></big> </div>")
  } else {
    return("<div> <span style ='color:green'>   <big><big><big><big><big>&#11015;</big></big></big></big></big> </div>")
  }
    
}



combine_text <- function(direction, site, overall, baseline) {
  
  arrow_image <- assign_arrow(direction)
  
  overall = paste0(as.character(overall), "%")
  baseline = paste0("Baseline: ", as.character(baseline), "%")
  
  glue::glue(
    "{arrow_image}
    <div> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>{site}</div>
    <div> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>{overall}</div>
    <div> <span style='font-weight:bold;'>{baseline}</div>
    "
  )
}



df3 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(text_string = combine_text(direction, site, overall, baseline)) %>% 
  select(region, text_string) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(text_string = map(text_string, gt::html)) %>% 
  group_by(region) %>% 
  mutate(dummy = dplyr::row_number(),
         text_string = map(text_string, gt::html)) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = dummy, values_from = text_string) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Windows Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_New Zealand.1252
#>  ctype    English_New Zealand.1252
#>  tz       Pacific/Auckland
#>  date     2022-06-28
#>  pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ C:/Users/mcindoer/AppData/Local/Programs/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  backports     1.4.1   2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  broom         0.8.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  checkmate     2.1.0   2022-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  DBI           1.1.2   2021-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  dbplyr        2.1.1   2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.9   2022-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  forcats     * 0.5.1   2021-01-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  generics      0.1.2   2022-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  ggplot2     * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  gt          * 0.3.1   2021-08-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  haven         2.5.0   2022-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  hms           1.1.1   2021-09-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  httr          1.4.3   2022-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  jsonlite      1.8.0   2022-02-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  knitr         1.39    2022-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  lubridate     1.8.0   2021-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  modelr        0.1.8   2020-05-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  readr       * 2.1.2   2022-01-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  readxl        1.4.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rmarkdown     2.14    2022-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  rvest         1.0.2   2021-10-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  scales        1.2.0   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tibble      * 3.1.7   2022-05-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tidyr       * 1.2.0   2022-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.2   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tidyverse   * 1.3.1   2021-04-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  tzdb          0.3.0   2022-03-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  xfun          0.30    2022-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.3)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/working/ioc_cip_report/renv/library/R-3.6/x86_64-w64-mingw32
#>  [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.3/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Linux Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
#>  os       Red Hat Enterprise Linux
#>  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#>  ui       RStudio
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#>  tz       Pacific/Auckland
#>  date     2022-06-28
#>  rstudio  1.1.456 (server)
#>  pandoc   1.19.2.1 @ /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#>   ! package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>   2 assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 backports     1.4.1   2021-12-13 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 base64enc     0.1-3   2015-07-28 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 blastula    * 0.3.2   2020-05-19 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 broom         0.8.0   2022-04-13 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 callr         3.7.0   2021-04-20 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 cellranger    1.1.0   2016-07-27 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 checkmate     2.1.0   2022-04-21 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 colorspace    2.0-3   2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 commonmark    1.8.0   2022-03-09 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 crayon        1.5.1   2022-03-26 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 curl          4.3.2   2021-06-23 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 DBI           1.1.2   2021-12-20 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 dbplyr        2.1.1   2021-04-06 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 dplyr       * 1.0.9   2022-04-28 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 fansi         1.0.3   2022-03-24 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 forcats     * 0.5.1   2021-01-27 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 generics      0.1.2   2022-01-31 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 ggplot2     * 3.3.6   2022-05-03 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 gt          * 0.3.1   2021-08-07 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 haven         2.5.0   2022-04-15 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 here          1.0.1   2020-12-13 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 hms           1.1.1   2021-09-26 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 httr          1.4.3   2022-05-04 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 jsonlite      1.8.0   2022-02-22 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 kableExtra  * 1.3.4   2021-02-20 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 knitr         1.39    2022-04-26 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 lubridate   * 1.8.0   2021-10-07 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 modelr        0.1.8   2020-05-19 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 processx      3.5.3   2022-03-25 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 ps            1.7.0   2022-04-23 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 rappdirs      0.3.3   2021-01-31 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 readr       * 2.1.2   2022-01-30 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 readxl        1.4.0   2022-03-28 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   1 renv          0.15.4  2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 reprex      * 2.0.1   2021-08-05 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 rJava         0.9-11  2019-03-29 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 RJDBC         0.2-8   2020-03-10 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 rmarkdown     2.14    2022-04-25 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 rprojroot     2.0.2   2020-11-15 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 rvest         1.0.2   2021-10-16 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 sass          0.4.1   2022-03-23 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 scales        1.2.0   2022-04-13 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 sodium        1.1     2017-03-30 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 stringr     * 1.4.0   2019-02-10 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 svglite       2.1.0   2022-02-03 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 systemfonts   1.0.4   2022-02-11 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 tibble      * 3.1.7   2022-05-03 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 tidyr       * 1.2.0   2022-02-01 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 tidyselect    1.1.2   2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 tidyverse   * 1.3.1   2021-04-15 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 tzdb          0.3.0   2022-03-28 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 utf8          1.2.2   2021-07-24 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 uuid          1.1-0   2022-04-19 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 vctrs         0.4.1   2022-04-13 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 viridisLite   0.4.0   2021-04-13 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 webshot       0.5.3   2022-04-14 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 xfun          0.30    2022-03-02 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 xml2          1.3.3   2021-11-30 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>   2 yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#> 
#>  [1] u/apps/Rcode/ioc_cip_report/renv/library/R-3.5/x86_64-linux-gnu
#>  [2] usr/lib64/R/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

On Windows:
[Windows output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJDXI.png)

On Linux:
[Linux output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUAh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with OP, and I have done some more digging into the problem. It appears to be a problem with `gt::html` running on Rv3.5.2 (even on Windows).

I used Rv3.6.3 to successfully create the output.
I then ran `renv::init()` then `renv::snapshot()`.
I then switched to Rv3.5.2 and ran `renv::restore()`
Then the output did not display correctly.

A simpler example of the correct output on R 3.6.3:

[image]

What the output from R 3.5.2 is:
[image]

Reprex from R 3.6.3

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)
library(gt)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble::tribble(~x,
                      "<div><span style ='color:green'><big>&#11015;</big></div>") %>%
  mutate(x = map(x, gt::html)) %>% 
  gt()
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
#> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
#> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.1252   
#> [3] LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                        
#> [5] LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.1252    
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] purrr_0.3.4  gt_0.6.0     tibble_3.1.6 dplyr_1.0.8 
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] pillar_1.7.0     compiler_3.6.3   highr_0.9        tools_3.6.3     
#>  [5] digest_0.6.27    checkmate_2.0.0  evaluate_0.15    lifecycle_1.0.1 
#>  [9] gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.2      reprex_2.0.1    
#> [13] cli_3.3.0        rstudioapi_0.13  yaml_2.3.5       xfun_0.31       
#> [17] fastmap_1.1.0    withr_2.5.0      stringr_1.4.0    knitr_1.39      
#> [21] generics_0.1.0   fs_1.5.2         vctrs_0.3.8      grid_3.6.3      
#> [25] tidyselect_1.1.1 glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1         fansi_0.4.2     
#> [29] rmarkdown_2.14   ggplot2_3.3.5    magrittr_2.0.2   backports_1.2.1 
#> [33] scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.2   htmltools_0.5.2  colorspace_2.0-1
#> [37] utf8_1.2.1       stringi_1.6.2    munsell_0.5.0    crayon_1.5.0
```

Reprex from R 3.5.2

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)
library(gt)
library(purrr)
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.5.3

df <- tibble::tribble(~x,
                      "<div><span style ='color:green'><big>&#11015;</big></div>") %>%
  mutate(x = map(x, gt::html)) %>% 
  gt()
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19042)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_New Zealand.1252
#>  ctype    English_New Zealand.1252
#>  tz       Pacific/Auckland
#>  date     2022-06-28
#>  pandoc   2.17.1.1 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/quarto/bin/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  backports     1.2.1   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  checkmate     2.0.0   2020-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  cli           3.3.0   2022-04-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  colorspace    2.0-1   2021-05-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  crayon        1.5.0   2022-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  DBI           1.1.3   2022-06-18 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  digest        0.6.27  2020-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  dplyr       * 1.0.8   2022-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  evaluate      0.15    2022-02-18 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  fansi         0.4.2   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  generics      0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  ggplot2       3.3.5   2021-06-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  gt          * 0.6.0   2022-05-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  gtable        0.3.0   2019-03-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  knitr         1.39    2022-04-26 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  lifecycle     1.0.1   2021-09-24 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  magrittr      2.0.2   2022-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  munsell       0.5.0   2018-06-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  pillar        1.7.0   2022-02-01 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  pkgconfig     2.0.3   2019-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  purrr       * 0.3.4   2020-04-17 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  rlang         1.0.2   2022-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.14    2022-04-25 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  scales        1.1.1   2020-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  stringi       1.6.2   2021-05-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
#>  tibble      * 3.1.6   2021-11-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  tidyselect    1.1.1   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  utf8          1.2.1   2021-03-12 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  vctrs         0.3.8   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  withr         2.5.0   2022-03-03 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  xfun          0.31    2022-05-10 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#>  yaml          2.3.5   2022-02-21 [2] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/working/My_R_Scripts/gt_html_reprex/renv/library/R-3.5/x86_64-w64-mingw32
#>  [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.2/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```